# Journey Builder - stop sending emails after field value change

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have one question I have build a journey on the basis of Lead Status= "Open" to send series of email on Day 1 ,Day 5 and Day 7.Lead has entered into the Journey but after 2-3 days Lead Status has been changed to "Closed".

The Lead is still receiving email as it should exit the journey.

Can you please help me how I can stop the emails when status has been changed.

Answer (score 2):

There are two common ways to do this:

- **Approach 1:** You need to define the status Closed as goal criteria and select the option to eject contacts as soon as they fulfill the goal. *(Easier if you have multiple emails and splits in your journey as it is a "global" approach)*
- **Approach 2:** You add decision splits before every email activity, checking for the status. *(More suitable if you only have one or two Follow-Up emails)*

**Related documentation:**

- *Approach 1:*

  - [Goals](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/goals/)
  - [Define a Goal](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/goals/define_a_goal/)
- *Approach 2:*

  - [Use Decision Splits](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/canvas_activities/using_decision_splits/)

Comment: Also, if you have an event data extension, it's values are static.  So you'll need to base your decision split on other data defined in Contact Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to put decision split before every email to check leads status are closed or still open.

if open they will receive 2nd email else they will exit from that journey.